# How to disable the ability to pause/play an AVPlayer connected to an Apple TV via Airplay

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, apple-tv

I am working on an iOS app that uses an `AVPlayer` to stream live media. When connected to an Apple TV via Airplay it is possible to pause and resume the content using the Apple TV remote.

I am looking for a way to disable this ability.

I have tried using: `- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)receivedEvent` which works for headset remote and lock screen control events, but not Apple TV.

I have also tried playing with `MPRemoteCommandCenter` which does not intercept events from the Apple TV either.

Comment: You found a solution already?

Comment: My understanding is that it is not possible to accomplish this. Since a live stream is served in segments, it is possible to seek within these segments along with pausing and playing.

Answer (score 1):

I was to achieve this AVPlayerController. Yet to test in device.

First implement play/pause gesture in AVPlayercontroller:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(PlayPause)];
tapGestureRec.allowedPressTypes = @[@(UIPressTypePlayPause)];
[self.playerViewController.view addGestureRecognizer: tapGestureRec];
```

Implement gesture method and always call play method from it:

```
-(void)PlayPause {
    [self.playerViewController.player play];
    NSLog(@"Do Anything or Nothing");
}
```

Also add the observer to capture first-time pause button press:

```
[player addObserver: self forKeyPath: @"rate" options: (NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial) context: nil];
```

Then call player play method from the pause event in "rate" observer:

```
// When rate is 0.0, it means the player has stopped
if (![self.player rate]) {
     if(self.isLiveStream) {
         [self.playerViewController.player play]; // Disable pause in Live stream
     }
}
```

In `viewDidLoad`, set linear playback flag as true to disable seek controls:

```
self.playerViewController.requiresLinearPlayback = true;
```